# No element found at the end of the XML file using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Python newbie here. I am just practicing extracting certain elements from XML files. I am going through this [Datacamp tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-xml-elementtree), and am trying parse the "movies" XML file provided a the beginning of the tutorial.

It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<collection>
    <genre category="Action">
        <decade years="1980s">
            <movie favorite="True" title="Indiana Jones: The raiders of the lost Ark">
                <format multiple="No">DVD</format>
                <year>1981</year>
                <rating>PG</rating>
                <description>
                'Archaeologist and adventurer Indiana Jones 
                is hired by the U.S. government to find the Ark of the 
                Covenant before the Nazis.'
                </description>
            </movie>
               <movie favorite="True" title="THE KARATE KID">
               <format multiple="Yes">DVD,Online</format>
               <year>1984</year>
               <rating>PG</rating>
               <description>None provided.</description>
            </movie>
            <movie favorite="False" title="Back 2 the Future">
               <format multiple="False">Blu-ray</format>
               <year>1985</year>
               <rating>PG</rating>
               <description>Marty McFly</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <decade years="1990s">
            <movie favorite="False" title="X-Men">
               <format multiple="Yes">dvd, digital</format>
               <year>2000</year>
               <rating>PG-13</rating>
               <description>Two mutants come to a private academy for their kind whose resident superhero team must 
               oppose a terrorist organization with similar powers.</description>
            </movie>
            <movie favorite="True" title="Batman Returns">
               <format multiple="No">VHS</format>
               <year>1992</year>
               <rating>PG13</rating>
               <description>NA.</description>
            </movie>
               <movie favorite="False" title="Reservoir Dogs">
               <format multiple="No">Online</format>
               <year>1992</year>
               <rating>R</rating>
               <description>WhAtEvER I Want!!!?!</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>    
    </genre>

    <genre category="Thriller">
        <decade years="1970s">
            <movie favorite="False" title="ALIEN">
                <format multiple="Yes">DVD</format>
                <year>1979</year>
                <rating>R</rating>
                <description>"""""""""</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <decade years="1980s">
            <movie favorite="True" title="Ferris Bueller's Day Off">
                <format multiple="No">DVD</format>
                <year>1986</year>
                <rating>PG13</rating>
                <description>Funny movie about a funny guy</description>
            </movie>
            <movie favorite="FALSE" title="American Psycho">
                <format multiple="No">blue-ray</format>
                <year>2000</year>
                <rating>Unrated</rating>
                <description>psychopathic Bateman</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
    </genre>
```

I understand that I must add
`</collection>` at the end in order to parse the file. However, I am still thrown the error:
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 74, column 12

When running the code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('movies.xml')
```

Is the last "genre" element closed incorrectly? I'm not sure why I am unable to parse the file. Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Good you posted the input data. But to help you, please post your code as well to see exactly what it does. Your code does not seem to cause an error, so what exactly goes not as expected?

Comment: @DanielHaley Yes, the apostrophe was indeed a typo - my bad!

Comment: The only way I can reproduce that exact error is if I don't have the `</collection>` element in the file. Are you sure you saved `movies.xml` after adding `</collection>`?

Comment: I can't seem to find anything weird, I can normally parse the file.

Comment: @Ronald Just updated. Playing around, it now works. I think it may have been because I had an unnecessary os.chdir statement before parsing.

Comment: Open this XML file in e. g. a Notepad++ and check the XML validity by its inbuilt/plugin functionality, also online service homepage could help. E. g. https://www.xmlvalidation.com/? Some will even tell you the problem if there is one.

Comment: Lol, yes that doesn't help to find the file, does it? Glad you solved it.

Comment: @emomura: Glad you found it: better use/create absolute paths (os.path.join...) than using os.chdir - this programming style that can cause a lot trouble and is not best practise. I would personally limit the os.chdir usage to a minimum.

Comment: @BitLauncher I see. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unnecessary os change directory statement after importing packages and prior to parsing XML file.

Code that threw error:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
os.chdir('filepath')
tree = ET.parse('movies.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

Once `os.chdir` statement was removed, it parsed with no error.

Comment: Remember that you can pass the entire file path to the `parse()`, so changing directories isn't necessary here.